# API Gateway caching not calling Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm using Amazon API Gateway to execute a Lambda function when the API endpoint is called. In my Lambda function I'm updating a DynamoDB table.

Whenever I call the API with caching disabled using Chrome Developer Tools, the DynamoDB table is updated.

When I have caching enabled, the first request from my API updates the table, every subsequent request is much faster but doesn't update the table.

I'm assuming that CloudFront is caching the responses so as to not have to call the Lambda function each time.

Is there any way to force the Lambda function to be executed with each request?

Comment: The entire point of caching is to not call the Lambda function. It sounds like you don't actually want caching enabled.

Comment: @MarkB I don't want caching but CloudFront is added automatically when you add a custom domain name.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question. First make sure you have caching disabled in the API settings. If you have that disabled then CloudFront won't cache your API responses. It sounds like your actual issue is caching in the browser. What is the `cache-control` header value in your API responses?

Comment: By default it's cache-control: private, when I use Chrome Developer Tools it's cache-control: no-cache.

Comment: I think you're correct, it's just the browser cache. I thought CloudFront was responding to the cache-control header.

Comment: Yeah I think you need to configure your API Gateway mapping template to always return `cache-control: no-cache` if you want to prevent browsers from caching the response.

Comment: Additionally, your redirect can't be a 301.  You need a 302, because browsers are supposed to cache 301 since it means `Moved Permanently` by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few possible solutions:

1. CloudFront should be used only when u want caching. In this case you don't need it; so call API endpoint directly from browser instead of calling CF end point. This will also save your cloudfront cost.
2. With each request add a timestamp.
3. If you have to use CF; you can configure it very easily as to what requests should ALWAYS go to API end points ( which serves dynamic content) while which one should be cached.
4. Probably you are calling CF as a GET request; just make it POST which is NEVER cached. Ideally, as you are updating table it should be a POST request. This should be simplistic solution with minimal and right changes.

Comment: I think CloudFront is added by default because even calling the API directly seems to have the same problem.

Comment: The problem is I want the API to be called using a GET request, I'm creating a simple URL shortening application that is powered by Lambda, but I have to use API Gateway to be able to call it. Would it work if I tell the GET request to send a POST request to my API? I tried it and it hasn't worked so far, I'm not sure if that just because of the caching though.

Comment: I have done it in past. Just use https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/build-a-serverless-private-url-shortener/

Comment: are you 100% sure that POST will never be cached even when caching option is less granular (set on stage level vs particular request)? [in the scope of API gateway settings]

Comment: @Francis GET request is not supposed to modify data (theoretically GET should not modify anything but logs) and used solely to retrieve data.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know but my GET request only modifies a counter that records the number of views when you visit an endpoint.

Comment: FWIW, CloudFront provides some front-end capabilities to all API Gateway deployments, so it is always inline and you'll see `X-Cache` and other response headers, but is not doing any of its traditional web caching.